# Не выполняется функция после нажатия

Tags: jquery, ajax

Всем привет. Почему то после нажатия на кнопку ни чего не происходит вроде все правильно...помогите пожалуйста...

```
<div class="dialog-get-call dialog-wrapper" action="/zakaz.php">
<div class="dialog">
<form data-type="get-call">
    <div class="form-group">     
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
    </div>    
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон" maxlength="18" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="f-button-orange" id="dialog-get-call-submit">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

</div>

```
    $('#dialog-get-call-submit').click(function(){
        if(i !== 0){
            alert('беда');
        }
        else {
            var name = $("input[name='name']").val();
            var phone = $("input[name='phone']").val();
            var email = $("input[name='email']").val();

            var length_name = name.length;
            var length_phone = phone.length;
            var length_email = email.length;

            if(length_name > 2 && length_phone > 2 && length_email > 2){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:"./zakaz.php",
                    data:{"name":name,"phone":phone,"email":email},
                    success: function(dialog-get-call-submit){
                        i++;
                        $("input[name='name']").val('');
                        $("input[name='phone']").val('');
                        $("input[name='email']").val('');

                        alert('Запрос отправлен');
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }else {
                alert("Заполните форму");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: заверните ваш код в `$(function() {/* тут ваш код*/})`  и вместо click лучше используйте submit.

Comment: не помогло :(

Comment: народ очень надо сделать....помогите пожалуйста..выскажите любые ваши предложения..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. сразу после click() поставьте alert() так можно выяснить что вообще на click на этот id чтото повешено
2. если не срабатывает, то обернуть так как посоветовали выше
3. javascript очень рекомендуется выполнять в конце самом и в указанной выше обертке, ибо на момент выполнения скрипта объект может быть еще не инициализирован браузером.

и вообще, что за несуществующая переменная i? она вообщето null, и, ЕМНИП, она не попадет ни в true ни в false, ее просто не существует. но могу ошибаться.

Comment: она есть просто это маленькая часть всего кода

Comment: не появляется алерт...

Comment: начните с малого, проверьте, что обработчик вообще повесился на кнопку. если да, то проверить что содержит переменная `i`, можно в консоль вывести можно в alert()  
ну и так, потихоньку все проверять.

Comment: сейчас открою один секрет который я забыл написать:) 
если убрать dialog-wrapper то код будет работать

Comment: тогда вполне может быть, что чтото переназначает click на этот диалог, то, что реагирует на dialog-wrapper -> button

Comment: хм...сейчас покопаюсь

Comment: попробуйте повесить на класс `f-button-orange`, если заработает, то значит чтото использует ваш id кнопки.

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(dialog-get-call-submit){
```

Внимательно смотрим на аргумент функции. Осознаём. Исправляем.

Comment: исправил не помогло все ровно после нажатия ни чего не происходит...(

Comment: Жмём F12, выбираем вкладку Console, перезагружаем страницу, пытаемся отправить. Читаем сообщения об ошибках, переходим к строкам, указанным в сообщениях. Осознаём. Исправляем.

Comment: как будто я не знал об этом...в консоли ни чего не пишет там пусто...

Comment: Учимся пользоваться отладчиком. Переходим на вкладку Script (Sources в Chrome), находим обработчик, ставим брейкпоинт, перезагружаем страницу. Пошагово выполняем обработчик до осознания. Или не выполняем, если он был установлен до загрузки DOM. В этом случае устанавливаем его через функцию [`.on`][1] и в случае отсутствия сообщений повторяем приведённую инструкцию.


  [1]: http://api.jquery.com/on/